# Azure Data Factory - Get Metadata (Child Items) For Each Sub-Directory

Tags: azure, recursion, foreach, azure-data-factory

**Objective:** For each sub-directory in a root directory (`DIRECTORY-B`), get all the child items iteratively. For this, I've a SFTP folder with the below hierarchy:

```
SFTP_FOLDER
  - DIRECTORY-A
  - DIRECTORY-B
    - Sub-Directory I
      - a.csv
      - b.csv
    - Sub-Directory II
      - c.csv
    - Sub-Directory III
      - d.csv
      - e.csv
  - DIRECTORY-C
```

For this, I've setup a two-step approach: `GetMetadata > ForEach(GetMetadata)` to get all the files in sub-directory.

[image: ADF Pipeline Description]

I'm able to get all the directories from `GET Directory Structure`, however I am not able to parametrize the directory name in `GET File List`, which is configured like:

[image: GET File List - Settings]

Dataset Description:

[image: Dynamic Directory Settings]

[image: Pipeline Expression Builder]

Though all the values are passed properly, the child items are not retrieved from the directory. My question: How to make the folder name dynamic keeping `SFTP_FOLDER/DIRECTORY-B` constant?

Alternatively, is there a simple way to recursively find and copy the latest modified files in a directory with subdirectories from source to sink?

NOTE: I've to go from folder to folder, and wildcard like `SFTP_FOLDER/DIRECTORY-B/*/*.csv` is not applicable as I want to retrieve only the latest file from each directory.

This question is similar to [Q63566122](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63566122), however I have already implemented the mentioned process but not able to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use data flow instead of get metadata to use wild card path for file path as follows:

Create a dataset with an SFTP folder and select it as the data flow source dataset. Go to source settings and use `DIRECTORY-B/*/*.csv`. Add the column, and if you want, you can also add the **Start time** (`subDays(currentUTC(),1`) and **End time** (`currentUTC()`) filters for the files, but make sure to change the expression as per your time as shown below:

[image]

Here, regardless of the file structure, all rows will be merged, and a column will be added containing the file path for each specific row, as shown below:

[image]

Use aggregation transformation, group it by **filepath** column, and create a sample column for aggregation. Select the **filepath** column using select transformation, add sink transformation, and select cache as the sink type. Check **Write to activity output** as shown below:

[image]

If you execute the data flow, you will get the output as shown below:

[image]

To get the latest file from **DIRECTORY-B**, add a for each activity on the success of the data flow and give the below expression:

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value
```

Add a get metadata activity inside the foreach. Select a dataset with a parameter for the file name and add `@item().filepath` expression for the parameter. Create **Last modified** and **Item name** under the field list as shown below:

[image]

Create two variables named **refd** with 1900-01-01 00:00:00 value to get the latest modified date of the file and **ltf** to store the latest modified file name. Add an if condition and use the below expression to compare file modified dates with the **refd** variable value:

```
@greater(activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified,variables('refd'))
```

If True, add a set variable activity inside True. Call the **refid** variable and add the below expression as the value. Update the variable with the last modified date:

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified
```

On the success of the set variable, add another set variable and call **ltf**. Add the below expression to store the latest modified file name:

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName
```

On the success of the foreach, add a set variable, and add `@variables('ltf')` expression as the value for the variable to store the latest modified file. If you debug the pipeline, you will get the latest modified file of DIRECTORY-B as shown below:

[image]

For your reference here is
**Dataflow Json:**

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText5",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "aggregate1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select1",
                    "description": "Renaming aggregate1 to select1 with columns 'filepath'"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          Id as string,",
                "          Name as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     rowUrlColumn: 'filepath',",
                "     modifiedAfter: (subDays(currentUTC(),1) ),",
                "     modifiedBefore: (currentUTC()),",
                "     wildcardPaths:['DIRECTORY-B/*/*.csv']) ~> source1",
                "source1 aggregate(groupBy(filepath),",
                "     cnt = count(filepath)) ~> aggregate1",
                "aggregate1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          filepath",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "select1 sink(validateSchema: false,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     store: 'cache',",
                "     format: 'inline',",
                "     output: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Pipeline Json:**

```
{
    "name": "subdf",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Data flow1",
                "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataflow": {
                        "referenceName": "dataflow1",
                        "type": "DataFlowReference"
                    },
                    "compute": {
                        "coreCount": 8,
                        "computeType": "General"
                    },
                    "traceLevel": "None",
                    "cacheSinks": {
                        "firstRowOnly": false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Data flow1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value\n",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata1",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText6",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "fileName": {
                                            "value": "@item().filepath",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "lastModified",
                                    "itemName"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "SftpReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false,
                                    "disableChunking": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "If Condition1",
                            "type": "IfCondition",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "expression": {
                                    "value": "@greater(activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified,variables('refd'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "ifTrueActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "referencedate",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "refd",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "ltf",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [
                                            {
                                                "activity": "referencedate",
                                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                                    "Succeeded"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "ltf",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "fnwlmd",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "fnwlmd",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@variables('ltf')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "latest file": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "refd": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "1900-01-01 00:00:00"
            },
            "ltf": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "fnwlmd": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```